# Safari cutting off dashed borders' first and last dashes

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, border

I have an element with a dashed bottom border:

```
border-bottom: #303030 2px dashed !important;
```

In Chrome, it nicely gets rendered like this, with the dashes all having the same length:

[image: Chrome]

However, Safari behaves differently. The first and last dash gets cut off on the side:

[image: the dashed border]

Here's a minimal Codepen to reproduce: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBJjJP

I have tried achieving the dashed effect with a background image, which gives me exactly the same issue in Safari.

Do you guys have a solution for having Safari render the dashes the same way Chrome does?

Comment: Ok, I'll say it: Aren't you being a bit too sensitive to minor differences in the way a border is rendered? No visitor will spot this. It will vary from browser to browser anyway, so why bother about such a detail in one browser?

Comment: The client wants it perfectly done, the client gets it perfectly done ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a (hacky) solution that makes it work in Safari, too: Have a fully transparent border to reserve the space, then add a background image below the element that draws the actual border:

```
border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,0) 2px dashed !important;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 60%, 
rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
background-size: 11px 2px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: left calc(100% + 2px);
```

I needed to adapt the exact dash width (11px in this case) to the concrete element's width. So I doubt this solution will work well in responsive design scenarios, but it is at least sufficient for me.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a hack/bodge.